# Im Getting a Logical Error, and Idk what to do. Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

The Terminal is saying that my string is empty, and it isnt showing up on my GUI either. I am trying to get the 'AVarStr' to display the calculations, but it appears to be empty. Down below is the method that contains the frame, and below that is the the statement that shows what happens when the button is clicked. Below that is the InterCalc class. Thanks for the Help!

!!!EDIT!!! The error in the program is really that one of the variables cannot be blank, it has to be filled in, which it isn't supposed to do. It is supposed to find one of the variables, while leaving one space blank to indicate the missing variable. Thanks!

```
public void setPythag()
        {
            pythagFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            pythagFrame.setBounds(300,200,600,700);
            pythagFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            pythagFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(pythagColor);

            pythagPanel.setBackground(pythagColor);
            pythagPanel.add(pythagLabelA);
            pythagPanel.add(pythagTextA);
            pythagPanel.add(pythagLabelB);
            pythagPanel.add(pythagTextB);
            pythagPanel.add(pythagLabelC);
            pythagPanel.add(pythagTextC);

            buttonPanel2.setBackground(pythagColor);
            pythagCalcC.addActionListener(this);
            pythagCalcA.addActionListener(this);
            pythagCalcB.addActionListener(this);
            pythagHome.addActionListener(this);
            buttonPanel2.add(pythagCalcA);
            buttonPanel2.add(pythagCalcB);
            buttonPanel2.add(pythagCalcC);
            buttonPanel2.add(pythagHome);
            pythagAns.add(pythagAnsA);
            pythagAns.add(pythagAnsB);
            pythagAns.add(pythagAnsC);
            pythagFrame.add(pythagAns, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            pythagFrame.add(buttonPanel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            pythagFrame.add(pythagPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            pythagFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String X1Str;
        double X1No;
        String X2Str;
        double X2No;

        String Y1Str;
        double Y1No;
        String Y2Str;
        double Y2No;

        String slopeStr;
        double slopeNo;

        String AVarStr;
        double AVarNo;

        String BVarStr;
        double BVarNo;

        String CVarStr;
        double CVarNo;

        String pythagAnsStr;
        double pythagAnsNo;

        String buttonCommand = e.getActionCommand();

        if(buttonCommand.equals("Pythagorean Therom"))
        {
            System.out.println("You choose the Pythagorean Therom");
            mainFrame.dispose();
            setPythag();

        }
        else if(buttonCommand.equals("Solve A"))
        {
                InterCalc pythagVarA = new InterCalc();
                AVarStr = pythagTextA.getText();
                AVarNo = Double.parseDouble(AVarStr);
                BVarStr = pythagTextB.getText();
                BVarNo = Double.parseDouble(BVarStr);
                CVarStr = pythagTextC.getText();
                CVarNo = Double.parseDouble(CVarStr);

                AVarNo = pythagVarA.CalcA(BVarNo, CVarNo);
                AVarStr = Double.toString(AVarNo);
                pythagAnsA.setText("The A Value is "+AVarStr);

                System.out.println(AVarStr);
                pythagFrame.validate();
                pythagFrame.repaint();
        }
public class InterCalc
```

{

```
public double CalcA(double B, double C)
{
    double A;
    B = B * B;
    C = C * C;
    A = C - B;
    A = Math.sqrt(A);

    return A;
}

public double CalcB(double A, double C)
{
    double B;
    A = A * A;
    C = C * C;
    B = C - A;
    B = Math.sqrt(B);

    return B;
}

public double CalcC(double A, double B)
{
    double C;
    A = A * A;
    B = B * B;
    C = A + B;
    C = Math.sqrt(C);

    return C;
}
public double CalcSlope(double X1, double X2, double Y1, double Y2)
{
    double rise;
    double run;
    double slope;
    rise = Y2 - Y1;
    run = X2 - X1;
    slope = rise / run;

    return slope;
}
public double CalcBVar(double slope, double X, double Y)
{
    double BVar;
    BVar = Y - (slope * X);

    return BVar;
}
```

}

Comment: What does `InterCalc.getText()` look like?  That is where `AVarStr` is getting its value from.

Comment: @SteveSmith public double CalcA(double B, double C)
 {
  double A;
  B = B * B;
  C = C * C;
  A = C - B;
  A = Math.sqrt(A);
  
  return A;
 }

Comment: I would add all of InterCalc to the question (unless it's massive) as I think that's where your problem lies.

Comment: @SteveSmith Ok I added it to the bottom of the code.

Comment: I can't see the getText() method.

Comment: I would just try stepping through the code and seeing what the values are at each stage.

Comment: @SteveSmith ok thanks for the advice!

Comment: @SteveSmith. I have pin pointed the error for the program unable for one of the spaces to be blank, which is vital for the program to be able to solve for 1 of the variables. Do u know how I could do that?

Comment: For better help sooner post a [mcve].